# Instance member cannot be used on type ; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have my View defined as below

```
struct detailPage: View {
    var body: some View {
         VStack() {
              let returnedValue = RNPayPassConnect.canAddPass("Text")
              if (returnedValue) {
                 ProgressView()
              }
         }
    }
}
```

I need to check the returned value from  from `canAddPass` function, so  I have written the code for that, but I am getting an error as

> Instance member 'canAddPass' cannot be used on type 'RNPayPassConnect'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Below is my `RNPayPassConnect` code

```
@objc(RNPayPassConnect)
class RNPayPassConnect: NSObject {
  let addPassViewController = PKAddPassViewController()
  
  @objc func canAddPass(_ someValue : String) -> Bool {
    let result = PKAddPaymentPassViewController.canAddPaymentPass()
    return result
  }
}
```

I tried with all possible solutions, but no help, so please can someone help me on this?

Comment: How about RNPayPassConnect().canAddPass("Text")? Or having it as a static or class function?

Answer (score 3):

You made `canAddPass` an instance method, but you are trying to call it on the `RNPayPassConnect` type rather than on an instance.

You either need to call it on an instance or change it into a static method

Static method:

```
@objc static func canAddPass(_ someValue : String) -> Bool {
    let result = PKAddPaymentPassViewController.canAddPaymentPass()
    return result
}
```

Or if you want to keep it an instance method, make sure you store an instance in your view and call it on that:

```
struct DetailPage: View {
    private let payPassConnect = RNPayPassConnect()

    var body: some View {
         VStack() {
              let returnedValue = payPassConnect.canAddPass("Text")
              if (returnedValue) {
                 ProgressView()
              }
         }
    }
}
```